# Admin pannel for Magento website

Tags: php, magento

[This is the website](https://www.garamloha.com/)

I have to fix some back-end problems with this website. I have `username` and `password` for admin but not login URL for Admin Panel

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: please show the code ...

Comment: Hey Mushahid..  code is on the back end of the website. And to access backend i need admin pannel url....

Comment: Isn't there a standard admin url? I mean one that can be found in the doc's for magento? Or, if changed, then why not ask those who changed it?

Comment: hi Rahul Thanks for your brief answer and  time its much appreciated... I have a question: ----- > Where can i locate local.xml File?

Comment: As pointed out in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475187/admin-pannel-for-magento-website#answer-35475780 you can find your local.xml from your Magento root in app/etc/local.xml

Comment: _code is on the back end of the website. And to access backend i need admin pannel url_ No, you don't... Fire up your sftp client and have a look at `app/etc/local.xml` to find the assigned admin route and get the credentials to stuff into phpmyadmin to read from the `core_config_data` table

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your database using phpmyadmin or command line then try below solution.

**Solution 1**

What you need to do is look for the path you want with a SQL query (or with a search if you are using phpmyadmin or a similar tool).

You could use this request :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";
```

This will select all the rows where the path contains "admin/url/", then you should be able to modify them.

If you are using phpmyadmin, you can go to the sql section and execute this command, or go to the search section, and search for the path you want to find.

If you do not find some value in core_config_data it means only one: if you never saved this value from system / configuration - there will be no such value in database.

In other words: After clean magento installation your core_config_data table contains only 10-20 lines. If you save any configuration - these values will appear in database.

---

**Solution 2**

How to change the Magento Admin URL / Path.

Note: Do NOT use the web interface in the Magento Admin Panel to change the admin URL, as this is known to cause severe problems.

**Step 1 - Change Path**

First, open the local.xml configuration file in your favorite text editor, or use the Text Editor in the cPanel File Manager. The file is usually located in the app/etc/ directory under your Magento installation.

Locate the following code segment:

```
 <admin>
      <routers>
        <adminhtml>
          <args>
            <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
          </args>
        </adminhtml>
      </routers>
    </admin>
```

Now, replace admin with your new admin path. This should be something personal which is hard to guess, use only letters or numbers - no special characters, then save the file.

**Step 2 - Refresh Cache**

The final step is to refresh your cache. Use an FTP client to delete the content of the `var/cache/` directory, or use the following `SSH command`.

(First, navigate to you Magento root directory)

```
   rm -rf var/cache/*
```

**Step 3 - Complete**

The change is now complete and you should try to log in via the new admin url - `http://yourmagentodomain/adminpath/`, replacing '`adminpath`' with the path you chose in the step above. If everything went fine, you should now be presented with the Admin Panel login screen at the new URL. The old admin login URL should return a 404 error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your admin path:

1. Open app/etc/local.xml
2. Find `<frontName><![CDATA[some-front-name]]></frontName>`
3. Copy the text of the frontname (I used some-front-name as example)
4. Past this frontname after your store base url, e.g.: https://www.garamloha.com/some-front-name
5. You can enter your admin

Answer (score 0):

Hide below line(95) in

/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

```
   // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```